Editing powershell prompt when user profile file doesn't exist
I want to edit my Powershell prompt, as discussed here https://superuser.com/questions/1259900/how-to-colorize-the-powershell-prompt. However, my $profile variable references a path which does not exist, C:\Users\ferdi\OneDrive\Documenti\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1. Specifically, the WindowsPowerShell folder does not exist. How do I find the true location of my $profile, so that I can edit it and change my prompt?
Thanks a lot!

The PowerShell console uses four (4) "profile"  scripts. See them using $PROFILE | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty.


The value of the automatic $PROFILE variable is the true location of your profile file, more accurately of the profile file for the current user (you) and the current host (the application hosting PowerShell, typically a console / terminal window).

For more information, including about the other profile files, see the conceptual about_Profiles help topic.

Even though $PROFILE is a string, it is decorated with properties that contain all profile paths, and a simple way to show them all is
$PROFILE | Select-Object *, or, more conceptually accurate,
$PROFILE | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty, as lit notes.


It is just that PowerShell doesn't create any profile files by default, and it doesn't even create the directories for them.

To create your $PROFILE file on demand - including its directory - use the following:
if (-not (Test-Path $PROFILE)) {
  New-Item -Force $PROFILE 
}


The Test-Path call guards against accidentally replacing an existing profile, because New-Item -Force not only creates parent directories as needed, but also replaces any existing file with a new, empty one.



To then edit your profile with Visual Studio Code, for instance, run code $PROFILE or, if no custom text editor is installed, use notepad $PROFILE.

Either way, if there's a chance that the file's content will (possibly over time) contain non-ASCII characters (e.g., é), be sure to save the file as UTF-8 with BOM, which is required for Windows PowerShell to read it correctly, and also works in PowerShell (Core) 7.


Great answer, as usual. All of the profile paths are NoteProperty types. What causes CurrentUserCurrentHost to be the one emitted when the $PROFILE variable is used? Do you want this as another question?

Thanks, @lit. The reason that $PROFILE is equivalent to the .CurrentUserCurrentHost ETS property value is that it is also declared as the value of the [string] instance that the $PROFILE variable is from a .NET perspective, wrapped in a (mostly) invisible [psobject] instance - see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/51b8e5d1dacd7884768529381d32e699a73839af/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/hostifaces/HostUtilities.cs#L130-L146
